# VIM xml syntax highlight error

Tags: xml, vim, syntax, attributes, highlight

[image: VIM xml syntax highlight error]

Can anybody please explain, why syntax highlight is correct only with extra space?

Comment: Maybe your XML does not contain a root?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with Vim 8.0.648; You need to find out which syntax group causes the highlighting. `:syn list` shows all active groups, but it's easier when you install the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin. When you have the name of the offending syntax group, you can investigate where it comes from; (the last lines of) `:scriptnames` may help.

Comment: @horcrux Yes, it hasn't, but it is not important for this issue.

Comment: @ZdenekSuchan are your sure? Does it highlight correctly if you add a single top root element?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt yes, i'm sure, i have tried it. Good advise is what Ingo wrote. But it'll take some time to check, what rule cause this issue.

Comment: @IngoKarkat thank you very much. After checking highlight by SyntaxAttr, I found out, that plugin luochen1990/rainbow make the issue.

Comment: Ah, nice! I've expanded my comment into a full answer. Please accept it by clicking on the outlined checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such things usually are caused by a plugin. You can try to reproduce the issue with plugins turned off (start Vim with `--noplugin` or even `-N -u NONE`; note that you may have to manually enable `:syntax on` and `:filetype plugin on`). If you don't the issue then, it's a plugin issue.

You then need to find out which syntax group causes the highlighting. `:syn list` shows all active groups, but it's easier when you install the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin. When you have the name of the offending syntax group, you can investigate where it comes from; (the last lines of) `:scriptnames` may help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ever curious about what syntax/grouping is being used, try this:

```
" show the groupings under cursor
command! SS echo map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")')
```

It merely assists in problem solving and of course won't fix your problem.

Move the cursor to what you're curious about, and run `:SS` to get output such as:

`['jsxRegion', 'xmlError']`